# how to find the offending usage of "using namespace std"?

Tags: c++, g++

I've tried to preprocess the file using -E. And still I cannot find any

```
using namespace std;
```

except in various function scopes from various boost include files....
The compiler attempts to adapt std::find to my usage of (myNamespace::)find() for code located inside myNamespace. I know how to solve this problem (by specifying which find() I would like to use), but I would rather find the reason.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you want to find `using namespace std;` why not just use the find function of your editor/IDE?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the question as written, but you might be encountering [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: I think we need to see the code in question, but typically a compiler will look to link within its scope, then it's parent's scope, then the parent's parent, etc. If you qualified it as `std::find` it shouldn't be mistaking the `std` and `myNamespace` namespaces, but I don't know enough about compilers to say that definitively.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I think my comment above answers your issue. You won't be able to use `std::find()`within your namespace while your namespace has its own `find()` implementation. Compilers work upwards from the most deeply nested scope, which would be `myNamespace`, then later `std`. You will have to use `std::`.

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question.

Comment: If ADL is not involved, and if you do not have `using namespace std;` or `using std::find` inside your `myNamespace` namespace (or outside the namespace in the translation unit), you will have to qualify `std::find` with `std::`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) provided by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) normal functions (in this case from the std namespace) can also be found without any

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
using std::find;
```

This can be prevented by putting the function name in parenthesis:

```
(find)(….)
```

I only was aware of this for operators but not for functions.